# Como utilizar Funções de Bloqueio (Lock Routines) do OpenMP?

Tags: c, c++, paralelismo, openmp

Preciso criar 5 algoritmos de fácil entendimento para cada uma das funções de bloqueio abaixo em C ou C++ para poder exemplificar o funcionamento de cada uma e apresentar para o pessoal da minha sala.

- omp_init_lock_with_hint
- omp_init_nest_lock_with_hint

O problema é que eu quase não compreendi o funcionamento das funções de bloqueio.
Estou utilizando como referência a documentação do OpenMP mais atualizada disponível no link: http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf (páginas 270 a 275).

Será que poderiam me explicar como funcionam as funções de bloqueio e ajudar a criar um exemplo utilizando uma das funções para que eu compreenda o funcionamento e possa criar outros exemplos para apresentar para minha turma?

Agradecido desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença entre as duas funções especificadas, `omp_init_lock_with_hint()` e `omp_init_nest_lock_with_hint()` é que aquela inicializa uma trava *simples* e esta inicializa uma trava *aninhada*.

A diferença entre os dois (além do óbvio que uma recebe uma `omp_lock_t *` e a outra uma `omp_nest_lock_t *`) é que uma tarefa que obtenha uma trava simples via `omp_set_lock()` **não pode chamar** `omp_set_lock()` **na mesma trava sem antes liberá-la** usando `omp_unset_lock()`, [sob pena de gerar um *deadlock*](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#page=285).

Outras tarefas OpenMP podem chamar `omp_set_lock()` numa trava já pertencente a uma tarefa diferente; elas travarão até que a tarefa que atualmente é a dona da trava a libere usando `omp_unset_lock()` (e que as outras tarefas na frente desta na fila de espera pela trava também obtenham e liberem a trava).

Já para uma `omp_nest_lock_t`, se a tarefa dona da trava chamar `omp_set_nest_lock()` nela, ela meramente incrementará um contador interno, e ao chamar `omp_unset_nest_lock()` este contador será decrementado. Se o valor do contador chegar a zero, a trava é liberada. Em outras palavras, embora a chamada de `omp_set_nest_lock()` numa trava já pertencente à tarefa não cause *deadlock*, a tarefa tem que emitir tantos `omp_unset_nest_lock()` quanto emitiu `omp_set_nest_lock()` antes da trava ser liberada.

Quanto aos exemplos de uso, vou precisar de algum tempo para restaurar o meu conhecimento em OpenMP, mas a ideia geral é que, com a trava simples, cada tarefa obtenha a trava com `omp_set_lock()`, efetue as operações síncronas e infalíveis (não levantam exceções) na região crítica, e depois libere a trava com `omp_unset_lock()`. No caso da nested_lock, a tarefa pode fazer coisas mais complexas, como obter a trava com `omp_set_nest_lock()`, esperar por um evento e chamar `omp_unset_nest_lock()` em uma *callback*.